# How can I print while loop results in textView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I have a "for-loop" in Kotlin which is going to run my code 6 times.

I also have a textView on the app and want to see these 6 results shown there.

I can easily `println()` the results.

However, If I set the text of textView to these results, it only gets the last result.

What I like to do printing out all 5 results in textView (*suggestedNums* ) as each result is a separate line.

Is it even possible?
Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

```
for (i in 1..6) {
   val s: MutableSet<Int> = mutableSetOf()

   //create 5 numbers from numbers
   while (s.size < 5) {
      val rnd = (numbers).random()
      s.add(rnd)
   }

   // remove all 5 random numbers from numbers list.
   numbers.removeAll(s)

   // sort 5 random numbers and println
   println(s.sorted())

   // set suggestedNums text to "s"
   suggestedNums.text = s.sorted().toString()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways

1. replace

   `suggestedNums.text = s.sorted().toString()`

   with

   `suggestedNums.text = suggestedNums.text.toString() + "\n" + s.sorted().toString()`
2. Create a string and append the results with "\n" and set the text outside the for loop

Comment: `suggestedNums.append(s.sorted().toString())
    suggestedNums.append("\n")`
this sorted out,  thanks for the help @Viswanath